# How to add dropout and attention in LSTM in kers in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have about 1000 nodes dataset where each node has 4 time-series. Each time series is exactly 6 length long.The label is 0 or 1 (i.e. binary classification).

More precisely my dataset looks as follows.

```
node, time-series1, time_series2, time_series_3, time_series4, Label
n1, [1.2, 2.5, 3.7, 4.2, 5.6, 8.8], [6.2, 5.5, 4.7, 3.2, 2.6, 1.8], …, 1
n2, [5.2, 4.5, 3.7, 2.2, 1.6, 0.8], [8.2, 7.5, 6.7, 5.2, 4.6, 1.8], …, 0
and so on.
```

I `normalise` my timeseries before I feed it into my LSTM model for classification.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(6,4)))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(data.shape) # (1000, 6, 4)
model.fit(data, target)
```

I am new to keras and that is why started with the simplest LSTM model. However, now I would like to make it into a level that I can use it at an industry level.

I read that it is good to add `dropout` and `attention` layers to the LSTM models. Please let me know if you think that adding such layers is applicable to my problem and if so how to do it? :)

Note: I am not limited to droupout and attention layers and happy to receive other suggestions that I can use to improve my model.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: A pretty simple way I found to implement attention: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to add dropout in lstm cell, you can try this

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(6,4), dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(data.shape) # (1000, 6, 4)
model.fit(data, target)
```

or using dropout between lstm cell, may consider below

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(6,4)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(6,4)))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(data.shape) # (1000, 6, 4)
model.fit(data, target)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you know how to do attention layers? :)

Comment: From my understanding, attention can be tricky to implement. I would start off by having a look at this library for keras https://github.com/thushv89/attention_keras

Comment: @MohamadZeina Thanks a lot Mohamad. Looking forward to see your answer :)